# How to post a form with ajax and return data in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

HI how to post a form and return data it will be a array as like this

```
{
"notes":'some notes',
"validUntil": '12/12/2015',
"status": 1,
"menuItemName": "HR Section",
"menuItemDesc": "gggg"
}
```

My code is this

```js
$('#add-menu-list .btn[data-attr=submit-btn]').on('click', function(){
                var formValidate = $('#add-menu-list').parsley().validate();
                validateFront();
               // console.log(formValidate);
               var menuName = $('input[data-api-attr=menuItemName]').val();
               var validUntil = $('input[data-api-attr=validUntil]').val();
               var menuStatus = $('input[data-api-attr=status]').val();
               var menuNote = $('textarea[data-api-attr=notes]').val();
               var menuDesc = $('textarea[data-api-attr=menuItemDesc]').val();

             var dataString = {
                                menuItemName: menuName, 
                                validUntil : validUntil,
                                status : menuStatus,
                                notes : menuNote,
                                menuItemDesc : menuDesc
                            };
                if(formValidate == true){
                    alert('success');
                    console.log(menuName + validUntil + menuStatus + menuNote + menuDesc);

                    var url = "xyz.html"; // the script where you handle the form input.

                    $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                         //  url: url,
                           dataType: "json",
                           
                           data: $(dataString).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                               alert(data); // show response 
                           }
                    });

                }else{
                    alert('Validation fail ');
                }

           });
```

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object.

Comment: ok than how to show data in alert in object

Comment: Give the object a `toString` method. Then you can simply `alert(myObject);` The `toString` method will be called and the output will be however you want it. Newlines in an alert need to be `\n`, rather than `<br>` The toString method should return the string that you wish to display.

Answer (score 2):

Since "data" is a server response i guess that your server return a json object. In this case you have to somehow inform the jquery's ajax that you expect a json response from server or you have to translate the "data" to a json object by your self.

It is best to follow the first option so you don t have to deal with the translation your self you can easily do that by giving an extra parameter tou your ajax reuest : `dataType: 'json',` this will do the trick!

Now that you have a proper response object from your request you can either stringify it with `var string_resp=JSON.stringify(data);` and then alert it `alert(string_resp)` or you can access its elements like that : `alert(data.status)` which will alert your object's status field etc.

so your code will be :

```js
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(menuName).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function(data)
    {
         alert(data); // will alert an object
         alert(data.status); // will alert object's status field in this case 1
         alert(JSON.stringify(data)) // will alert the object as a string
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you are sending only one value in serialize, serialize() should be on form element not on field element, like :

```
  $('#add-menu-list .btn[data-attr=submit-btn]').on('click', function(){  
       ...
        $.ajax({ 
          ...         
          data:$("#form").serialize();
          ...
          success: function(data)
                       {
                           alert(data.notes); // show response 
                           ....
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var myObj = {
     "notes":'some notes',
     "validUntil": '12/12/2015',
     "status": 1,
     "menuItemName": "HR Section",
     "menuItemDesc": "gggg"
    };
    
 myObj.toString = function()
 {
  var str = '';
  
  for (var property in myObj) 
  {
   if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(property) && (property != "toString") ) 
   {
    str += (property + ': ' + myObj[property] + "\n");
   // do stuff
   }
  }

  return str;
 }
 
 alert(myObj);
```